# erase a linebreak from a string in python

Tags: python, string, text, replace, line-breaks

I'm working with .txt files in python.

I have linebreaks in the text files. Example:

```
line1
line2
```

I need to get rid of those linebreaks for my code to work.

I tried everything: `text.replace("\n", "")`, when that didn't work, I wrote out the ord() of every character in the string and found out the linebreak character was 10, so I tried `text.replace(chr(10), "")`, when even that didn't work, I even got to the point of writing a terrible for cycle, out of despair, to replace the chars, whose ord() == 10, with an empty string.

Nothing works.

Please help, I really need to get rid of those linebreaks.

I'm desperate.

Thank you.

Edit: I need regular spaces (" ") to stay in my text files.

Comment: Just call [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) without arguments, it will clean all whitespaces (including newline).

Comment: @OlvinRoght Will it strip regular spaces too, though? I need those to stay in my text files...

Comment: Then call it with `'\r\n'`

Comment: rstrip removes the trailing whitespace at the end of the line, so you don't have to worry about it removing other whitespace characters.  This is what's normally used to remove the '\n' and '\r\n' at the end of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `replace` function should work, I'm not sure why it didn't work for you:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as test:
    for line in test:
        print(line.rstrip("\n", ""), end="")
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to have worked! I have no idea why this for loop worked while simple replace() didn't, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mymokol You can prevent `print` from adding a newline with `end=''`.

Comment: And no need to call `readlines`, you can just use `for lines in test:`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oops, my bad. Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. I have fixed the post.

Comment: Answer is accepted, but it's wrong. To remove trailing char you should use `.rstrip()`, cause `.replace()` will iterate over all string.

Comment: @OlvinRoght actually, the answer is right and your correction is wrong, as I understand it. The linebreaks don't only occur on the end of the text file. They occur in the middle, which is why I need to get rid of them in the first place. rstrip() would only get rid of the trailing ones, but i need to get rid of all the linebreaks in the whole string.

If I misunderstood you, I apologise and please correct me.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I don't need to print anything, I just need to get it as a string without linebreaks, and the code works with it further. It seems to work now, so ye

Comment: @Mymokol, I will excuse if you would show me how to read file line by line and have linebreaks in the middle.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I'm not reading it line by line, but the string as a whole.

Comment: @Mymokol, no, you do.

Comment: @OlvinRoght it's possible to read an entire file with `read` instead of `readline` or `readlines`.  But most people don't do it that way.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I know that it's possible, but in this code file consumed line by line which makes impossible any occurrence of newline char except trailing

Comment: @OlvinRoght but that's just this answer.  OP didn't show any reading code in the question.

Comment: @MarkRansom, doesn't replacement of newline to nothing in whole text look like an absurd task though? How to split it then? Or why it was splitted? Such a rare case, function misuse is more likely.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I've seen worse.  At least there's a possibility that it's harmless.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I agree, it just slows down execution, nothing important if lines are short, but if line is thousands chars long, it will make a difference.